# Entity Framework Core criação relacionamento one to many

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class Evento {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }    
    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public CasaShow CasaShow { get; set; }
    public float QuantDeIngressos { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public float ValorDoIngresso { get; set; }
    public DateTime Hora { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Venda {

    public int Id { get; set;}
    public IdentityUser  User { get; set; }        
    public List<Evento> Evento { get; set;}

}
```

---

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet <Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
    public DbSet <CasaShow> CasasShows { get; set; }    
    public DbSet <Evento> Eventos { get; set; }
    public DbSet <Venda> Vendas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder builder) {
        base.OnModelCreating (builder);
        builder.Entity<Venda>().HasMany(x => x.Evento);
        //Change my AspNetUser table to User
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser> ().ToTable ("User");
        //Change my AspNetRoles to Role
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole> ().ToTable ("Role");

    }
}
```

Quero uma relação de `one` `to` `many`, onde uma venda recebe vários eventos, mas o banco de dados não reconhece nenhuma das formas de declaração com `ICollection`, `IList`, `List` ou no `builder With Many`.

Comment: Deu certo a resposta pra você?

Answer (score 2):

Fez as relação errada, exemplo, na classe `Evento` pertence a uma `Venda`, então o seu modelo falta explicitar essa relação da seguinte forma, segue exemplo:

```
public class Evento {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }    
    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; } // problemas
    public CasaShow CasaShow { get; set; } // problemas
    public float QuantDeIngressos { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public float ValorDoIngresso { get; set; }
    public DateTime Hora { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    // isso configura a relação
    public int VendaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Venda Venda { get; set; }
}
```

e pelo visto tem `Categoria` e `CasaShow` também faltando `CategoriaId` e `CasaShowId` porque se não colocar e não relacionar ele vai pela convenção quando só coloca a classe.

Na [documentação da Microsoft isso é bem explicado](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) e você pode entender os motivos do `Framework` fazer assim.

Nesse [link sobre Convenções](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions) tem o exemplo de `1` para `N` entre `Blog` e `Post`:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

explicando como deveria ser as relações e como configurar as entidades.